# Specify get_title() if none found

Tags: rss, simplepie

I'm parsing some feeds using simplepie, I have an array with multiple rss urls, and I am storing it in the database. Along with the url I am also trying to store the get_title() which is like the source name. The problem is some feeds do not specify this so it's blank, as a result it's not storing in the database.

This is what I do to get the title:

```
$feed = $item->get_feed();  $sourcename = $feed->get_title();
```

I wondered if i could specify a default get_title as I know the names already, so something like:

```
$feed->set_feed_url(array('http://www.example.com/feed'=>'Example Feed',
                          'http://exampletwo.com/rss'=>'Example Two Feed')
```

Is it possible something like above or similar, perhaps I can avoid doing a condition and use something built it?

Comment: Since the set_feed_url method just uses the values of the array, you could try using your default title as the key.

Comment: @Revent what do you mean by default title? The one provided from the feed?

Comment: No, I mean in your example you are using the feed url as the array key and your "default title" as the value. Swap those.

Comment: @Revent ok tried that, however if I try to access it like $item[0] or $feed[0], I get this: Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type SimplePie_Item as array